# protractor actions.keydown vs selenium actions.keydown

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, geckodriver

Protractor: 5.4.1
Selenium: 3.14
geckodriver: 0.23
browser: firefox

Hi, i am getting a error "Failed: sendKeysToActiveElement" when execute following code

browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).click(elements).keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform()

However if i am trying to run it with selenium instead of protractor, it work with the following code

driver.actions({bridge:true}).keyDown(webdriver.Key.CONTROL).click(elements).keyUp(webdriver.Key.CONTROL).perform();

Is anyone experience on this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in the `Protractor` and `Selenium JS` code snippets is that the form doesn't perform the actions in **bridge mode** while the later does.

From the selenium [source at v3.14](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.14.0/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/input.js#L506),

```
 * In bridge mode, {@link #perform perform()} will first attempt to execute the
 * configured action sequence using the W3C action protocol. If this is rejected
 * by the remote end, the sequence will be translated to and executed against
 * the legacy protocol.
```

It seems that Gecko webdriver may not support the [W3C action protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#actions) and errors from the actions is [thrown](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.14.0/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/input.js#L506).

```
  if (this.bridge_
      && (ex instanceof UnknownCommandError
          || ex instanceof UnsupportedOperationError)) {
    return executeLegacy(this.executor_, this.sequences_);
  }
  throw ex;
```

Try running your actions in bridge mode for your Protractor tests.

```
actions = browser.actions({bridge: true})
actions.keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL)
  .click(elements)
  .keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL)
  .perform()
```

Comment: i trying with  browser.driver.actions({bridge:true}) and i getting an error of extra argument is being pass into actions

Comment: [protractor 5.4.1 uses selenium-webdriver 3.6.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/package.json#L27) which is an older version. The signature of the actions method there [doesn't receive any options](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.6.0/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L307)

Comment: ah, then it explain on protractor do not able to achieve with it . Thanks